# how to use only one loop for iterating over a file in Python?

Tags: python

I have a file that has the following data:

```
aaa97k:kkddd3046<br />
adfteak:xk666665<br />
ssyuri2:7r6669p<br />
k2fdf2k2:sgp54fa<br />
```

and I want to remove the part that says `<br />`

I have found a code that does that:

```
def main():
    fileR=open("data.txt","r")
    for line in (line.rstrip() for line in fileR):
        if line.endswith('<br />'):
            line=line[:-6]
            print line
```

for what I understand of this code the inner loop iterates over each line and return each of them without the new line character, am I right? then with this data it proceeds to get rid of the `<br />` part.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this using only one loop and maybe without the need of using `rstrip()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "second loop" is just a generator expression. It essentially runs in parallel with the actual loop; each iteration of the first loop simply reads a new value from the second. It's just a fancier way of writing

```
for line in fileR:
    line = line.rstrip()
```

A slightly better way of avoiding the second assignment to `line` (the first is by the `for` loop itself) is to use

```
from itertools import imap
from operator import methodcaller
stripper = methodcaller("rstrip")
for line in imap(stripper, fileR):
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop is a *generator expression*; the loop is not nested per se as *chained*.

You can remove it and manually account for the newline, sure. You won't gain anything by it though:

```
for line in fileR:
    if line.endswith('<br />\n'):
        line = line[:-7]
        print line
```

Now you need to test if the line ends in `<br />` *plus a newline*.

Note that if your last line in the file *doesn't* end in a newline, the above code will fail. `str.rstrip()` strips more than just a newline; if there are a (variable) number of spaces after the `<br />` text then those won't be handled by the above code either.

Comment: thanks, but when I execute it, it does not print anything; and yes each line ends up with a br plus a newline

Comment: @Layla: Are you certain there is no *other* whitespace after the `<br />`?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over each line, `split` on the `'<'` character, then grab the first part of the split.

```
with open("data.txt","r") as fileR:
    for line in fileR:
        line = line.split('<')[0]
        print line
```

Comment: And if the line contains *just* a `<` or even multiple `<` characters?

Comment: You are also now *unconditionally* printing the line; the original code only printed lines with `<br />` on it.

Comment: I just assumed the file looked identically like the one OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the original file with the lines, you can store them in a variable (how you did) and you can do further operations on them.

Otherwise if you just do some operations while reading, then rstrip() should fit. Here is also a smaller version of the script:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip('<br />')) # or do something else

    # the with statement cloeses the file automatically
```